# How can show when I am logging in for the first time in the storefront - T&C popup in hybris?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

How can show when I am logging in for the first time in the storefront - T&C popup in hybris?
For example I am a new customer and I am loggin in store front for the first time, then I will see a popup with some "T&C of use" that I must check to be able to enter the shop.
Maybe I must have some flag whom I say:

```
private boolean flag = false;
if user is login for first time
    flag = false;
        if(flag == false){
          show me pop up with T&C
          flag = true;
        }
```

But how can I get this last login or maybe have another way to do this?

Comment: You can take help of Cookie to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a boolean flag acceptedTAC on customer type? If someone requests a page on your storefront who has this flag set to null or false, you can show this popup. When the user clicks the accept button, do an AJAX request to your server and set the acceptedTAC flag to true.

This way you even have an "evidence" that a user accepted the TAC. Additionally you can query your database for users who did not yet accept the TAC.

However the usual way you would force the user to accept the TAC would be during registration. A user can only register when he/she accepts the TAC.

Here are the necessary steps:

myextension-items.xml

```
<itemtype code="Customer" ...>
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="acceptedTermsAndConditions" type="java.lang.Boolean">
      ..
    </attribute>
  <attributes>
</itemtype>
```

ShowTermsAndConditionsPopupBeforeViewHandler

```
public class ShowTermsAndConditionsPopupBeforeViewHandler implements BeforeViewHandler {

  @Resource 
  UserService userService;

  @Override
  public void beforeView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    UserModel user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user instanceof CustomerModel && !userService.isAnonymousUser(user)) {
      CustomerModel customer = (CustomerModel) user;
      modelAndView.addObject("showTermsAndConditionsPopup", BooleanUtils.isNotTrue(customer.isTermsAndConditionsAccepted()));
    } else {
      modelAndView.addObject("showTermsAndConditionsPopup", false);
    }
  }
}
```

Register BeforeViewHandler in spring-mvc-config.xml

```
...

<util:list id="defaultBeforeViewHandlersList">
...
    <bean class="my.package.ShowTermsAndConditionsPopupBeforeViewHandler"/>
...
</util:list>
...
```

Create JavaScript Variable in javaScriptVariables.tag

```
...
ACC.config.showTermsAndConditionsPopup=${showTermsAndConditionsPopup};
...
```

Add logic to open popup in JavaScript

```
...
if(ACC.config.showTermsAndConditionsPopup) {
   showPopup();
}
...
```

Create popup content with form:

```
<c:url var="url" value="/acceptTermsAndConditions" />
<form action="${url}" method="POST">
  <label for="acceptTermsAndConditions">I accept Terms and Conditions</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acceptTermsAndConditions" name="acceptTermsAndConditions" />
  <button type="submit>Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Create TermsAndConditionsController

```
@Controller
public TermsAndConditionsController {

  @Resource 
  private UserService userService;
  @Resource 
  private ModelService modelService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/acceptTermsAndConditions", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
  public void acceptTermsAndConditions() {
    UserModel user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user instanceof CustomerModel && !userService.isAnonymousUser(user)) {
      CustomerModel customer = (CustomerModel) user;
      customer.setAcceptedTermsAndConditions(true);
      modelService.save(customer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looked great, but my scenaria is when login for the first time, then this popup to show with T&C. How can I do this, like you tell? Can you give me a little code for example. I will be glad. Thank you :)

Comment: maybe, where can set on customer this flag to true. Something like if(user.getLastLogin() != null) { set flag=true } else { set flag=false) or have another way? And then somewhere to have loginsuccess() method and say, if( user.getflag == false) { show popup }

Comment: Many many thanks, after 10 minutes I will try to do this and I will write you if everything is alright

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to show T&C popup only once, I would say show it on Registration time.

Let's assume you want to show T&C on each login you can take help of the cookie.

The idea is, after successful login, check for the cookie(let's say "terms"), if not found then show your popup. Now based on user input you can store that cookie.

Just an example.

```
Source jsfiddle [ http://jsfiddle.net/9q8jmv3L/2/ ]


$(document).ready(function () {

    if(${loggedInUser})
    {
        var visit = getCookie("terms");
        if (visit == null) {
            x = confirm("Your Message Goes here and you only get to see it once!"); 
            if (x == true)
            {
                var expire = new Date();
                expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 7776000000);
                document.cookie = "terms=here; expires=" + expire;
            }     
        }
    }
});

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
```

---

**Commnent:**
If you really want to keep flag then you can have a new attribute in your customer model. Now check that attribute/flag inJavaScript on success login. If the flag is false show the popup. based on the user's action on the popup, update the flag using ajax call

Comment: An interesting idea, but is there a way to do that with flag as I have described above? And if there is how it can happen

Comment: If you really want to keep flag then you can have a new attribute in your customer model. Now check that attribute/flag inJavaScript on success login. If the flag is false show the popup. based on the user's action on the popup, update the flag using ajax call.

Comment: I have another question. What about if I use getLastLogin() from UserModel. I think getLastLogin() return null if user log in for the first time in storefront? How do you think? And to catch before authentication user, if this user have getLastLogin() == null then show me pop up. Then it will show up only once because next time this user will have getLastLogin() == 1?

Comment: If that is the case, then it would be great.

Comment: Yeah, i think so. I make debug and that it is. getLastLogin() if you login for the first time is null. Now, must found where it is make user authentication